# I need a list in a dynamodb using cloud formation

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

I have a users table, and a requests table. Many requests for one user. I would like to have a list of requests in the users table. But I am not sure how to write the cloud formation call to build it. Currently I have just a flat set of attributes:

```
resources:  
  Resources:
    DynamoDbTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: Employee
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: employeeid
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: name
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: requests
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: employeeid
            KeyType: HASH
```

I would like requests to be a list of request ids for the user, not a string value so no S type, so I can cycle through them and call the ones I want. Let me know if my schema is ok. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the following [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes). Notice that as long as you don't use the attribute as index you don't need to define it.

> DynamoDB is a NoSQL database, and is schemaless, which means that,
>   other than the primary key attributes, you do not need to define any
>   attributes or data types at table creation time.

So in your case, the `serverless.yml` should only specify:

```
resources:  
  Resources:
    DynamoDbTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: Employee
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: employeeid
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: employeeid
            KeyType: HASH
```

And in your code you can dynamically write into the table attributes which consist of sets, maps or even json.

Comment: wow, very loosy goosy. Gonna take some getting used to, but thanks.